# postgres psql giving permission denied but I can use pgadmin ok

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I get 
`psql: could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

but if I use pgadmin I can double click on a db and use it ok.

I think pg is running but permissions issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have set different permissions for connections from **Unix-domain sockets** and **TCP/IP connections**. I.e.: different entries in your [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file for `local` and `host`. Check the file and add lines for `local` accordingly.
Reload the server to have it take effect.

BTW.: I use `pg_lsclusters` on Debian for a quick check which db clusters are installed/running.